# Magento webhooks - Is there one yet?

Tags: magento

Does anyone knows how I can automate the export of my magento export files? I know one way is to use magento crons but is there webhooks that fires to the API when a user makes a change in his store like other platforms such as shopify?

Comment: This repo helped me: [https://github.com/gimmie/magento-webhooks](https://github.com/gimmie/magento-webhooks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at Magento's [event/observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method). Events are fired automatically on many actions within Magento, both frontend and backend (you can find them by searching for `Mage::dispatchEvent(`). You can observe these events with a custom module, and then perform any actions you want. For example, you can observe when a user saves changes to a product and call whatever code you want within your observer function.